# `mlockall` to another process

Tags: c, linux, memory

I would execute a `mlockall` on a real-time process [to lock the memory pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520499/linux-how-to-lock-the-pages-of-a-process-in-memory) that does no have root privileges. Since the user `ulimit` for max locked memory is really low (and it is ok due to security considerations), I would lock the memory via another process spawned by `root` user.

Unfortunately, `mlockall` has this signature:

```
int mlockall(int flags);
```

So, it works only if it is called directly by the target process. There exists a way (e.g. another syscall) to lock the memory of another process?
Something like:

```
int mlockall(int flags, pid_t pid);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINUX: How to lock the pages of a process in memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520499/linux-how-to-lock-the-pages-of-a-process-in-memory)

Comment: Injecting code with gdb is really a bad solution, it should be better to have a syscall or other mechanism that do not involve code injection.

Comment: How about starting the real-time process with necessary privileges, and using a small dynamic library to set the resource limits, process priority, and lock memory, *and* drop the privileges, before the actual process' `main()` starts? You do need one helper program (setuid) and the dynamic library, but they really should be quite straightforward to implement. Interested?

Comment: @RicoRico, you can always create that syscall yourself, maybe submit it upstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write a new system call in order to fill the gap.

I attached the patch to the kernel-mm mailing list, you can find it [here](http://marc.info/?l=linux-mm&m=148129782913314&w=2)